# Updating part of an observable used in async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, observable, async-pipe

We have a page where there are multiple sections. Each section can have a card or a table. An observable binds data in html using async pipe. Now I need to update one of the table without refreshing whole observable.

```
  loadPageData(Id): void {
    this.sections$ = this.psService.getLoadPageData(Id).pipe(
      switchMap(sections => forkJoin(
        sections.map(section => this.psService.getSectionData(section.sectionID).pipe(
          map(card => Object.assign({}, section, { card })),
          switchMap(c => c.card.map(card => iif(() => card.cardTypeId === 3,
            from(this.psService.getTable(this.tablePerodID).pipe(map(table => Object.assign({}, c, { table })))),
            of(c))))
        ).concatAll()
        ))
      ));
  }

  updateTable(sectionId, tablePerodID) {
    let tableData;
    this.psService.getTable(tablePerodID).subscribe((data) => {
      tableData = data;
    });
    this.sections$.forEach(sections => {
      sections.forEach(section => {
      if (section.sectionID === sectionId) {
        section.table = sectionData;
      }
    });
    });
  }
```

and the HTML is like:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of sections$ | async;">
  <div *ngFor="let card of section.card | sort:'displayOrder';">
    <app-card></app-card>
    <div *ngIf="card.cardTypeName === 'Table'">
      <app-table></app-table>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now the issue is when i try to load data for the table using updateTable [when user changes tablePerodID], it does nothing. I have tried `.next()` but it updates whole `section$`. Is there anyway i can only update table?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the tables are the same in each section, since they come from the same component-level `tablePeriodID`? So whenever `tablePeriodID` is updated, all tables are updated in the same way?

Comment: Tables can be different for each section.  Each section table header has a dropdown with periods. Idea is to update only the table in that particular section where that dropdown value changes.

Comment: Can you create this as a minimal stackblitz? It could be interpreted in several ways at the moment.

Comment: Also, how many possible tables are there? Should they always be asynchronously loaded, or could they all be initially loaded into memory?

Comment: At the very least, in the `updateTable` method, the forEach block `this.sections$.forEach` should be in the `subscribe` block of `this.psService.getTable` because this invocation is asynchronous. While this might not solve your immediate problem, it addresses an issue you'd most likely run into along the line. 

I could post an answer to illustrate this if my comment is not clear enough

Comment: Why are you not handling each section herself? You get the section and do an ng-container with ngFor and create an app-section. In this section you load each data for this section. In this section you do the same with card and table. So app-table and app-card. In each of this Components you load the data on ngOnInit. If the table is going to be changed through the dropdown with periods you easy trigger the method again in this table. Thats basically the core of angular. Divide and conquer! if you have an value thats going from parent to child you use an ViewChild, if not fine. #databinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @adrisons for giving me the idea of caching. Here is the solution that worked for me. It is slightly different from @adrisons answer in a way that it doesn't use observable.

```
  _cached: any; 
  sections$: Observable<any>;

  loadPageData(Id): void {
    // Load data from server
    this.sections$ = this.psService.getLoadPageData(Id).pipe(
      switchMap(sections => forkJoin(
        sections.map(section => this.psService.getSectionData(section.sectionID).pipe(
          map(card => Object.assign({}, section, { card })),
          switchMap(c => c.card.map(card => iif(() => card.cardTypeId === 3,
            from(this.psService.getTable(this.tablePerodID)
            .pipe(map(table => Object.assign({}, c, { table })))),
            of(c))))
        ).concatAll()
        ))
      ), first(), // Tap and get the first emit and assign to cache
      tap((data: any) => {
        this._cached = data // Caching the data without subscribing.
      }));
  }

  updateTable(sectionId, tablePerodID) {
    // Get table Data from backend and update cache
    this.psService.getTable(tablePerodID).subscribe((data) => {
      this._cached.map(section => {
        if (section.sectionID === sectionId) {
          section.table = data;
        }
      });
    });
    // Refresh async observable from cache
    this.refreshFromCache();
  }

  refreshFromCache() {
    this.sections$ = of(this._cached)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a misunderstanding of how pipes operate.

#### Simile

Think of the water pipes.

Imagine that you want a tap to pour sugar water.

If you take a glass of water from the tap and add sugar to it, you can no longer put that water in the tap again.

The solution would be to add a piece of pipe with a system to add sugar before you take the glass of water.

rxjs pipes are the same, once you subscribe, there's no going back. (unless you create a new pipe and pour the water into it ;)

The solution is to pipe everything. Only `subscribe` when you want to get the value. This has performance improvements too.

#### Solution

```js
this._cache$: BehaviorSubject<Section[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Section[]> ([]);
this.sections$: Observable<Section[]>;
```

```js
loadPageData(id: number): void {
    // subcribe once and save the values in the cache
    this.fetchPageData(Id).subscribe(data => this._cache$.next(data));

    // section$ will emit values when caché changes
    this.sections$ = this._cache$.asObservable();
}

fetchPageData(Id): Observable<Section[]> {
    // call your data service
    return this.psService.getLoadPageData(Id).pipe(
       //...
    );
}

updateTable(sectionId, tablePerodID) {
    let tableData;
    this.psService.getTable(tablePerodID).subscribe((data) => {
      tableData = data;
    });

    this.sections$ = this.sections$.pipe(
        map(sections => sections.map(section =>
        {
            if (section.sectionID === sectionId) {
                section.table = tableData;
             }
        })
    );
}
```

Instead of subscribing to the observable, pipe the update operation.

`updateTable` will update the `sections$` observable and the html async pipe will update the results.

Using the `_cache$` has another performance improvement, because each time you update the pipe it will not call your data service. (It's not necessary to use it)

Clarification: this will update your pipe in your app, not the data in a database or wherever.

Comment: This solution didnot work me as I'm trying to avoid refresh of whole section$ observable.

Comment: If you use the caché, the data will only be fetched when you call `loadPageData`, then you should use the observable. Subscribing to `sections$` observable will not trigger http calls